# Make query vulnerable to SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm doing some penetration testing in a toy application. The following code is making the application vulnerable so I can log in with `'or'1'='1`, but I'm not able to explore the tables with Sqlmap:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Query query = session
    .createSQLQuery("select * from product where product_id = '" + id + "' limit 0,1").addEntity(Product.class);

session.flush();

return (Product) query.uniqueResult();
```

I believe the `createSQLQuery` method allows only one statement and for that I think this method is the problem. How could I change it to be able to explore the tables with Sqlmap?

Comment: is your goal to explore tables, to explore tables with sqlmap or make a query vulnerable to SQL injection? It is not clear from your question. The latter is already done

Comment: this code is already vulnerable to sql injection, that's why i can log in with 'or'1'='1. what i want to do is make the code even more vulnerable so i can explore the tables via sqlmap or even manually. on the actual state, i cannot make a "union select table_name from information_schema.tables" for instance.